# C# access object properties at runtime

Tags: c#, object, reflection

[image]

I'm calling a web service that is returning this object.  I know I should be using object reflection in C# to access the property of `sentBatchTotal`.  However, I can't for the life of me figure out how to get to this property.  I have looked at several other articles here and on MSDN but it's just not sinking in.

Here is my code, what am I doing wrong?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    prdChal.finfunctions service = new prdChal.finfunctions();
    //Type thisObject = typeof()

    //Type myType = myObject.GetType();
    //IList<PropertyInfo> props = new List<PropertyInfo>(myType.GetProperties());

    String ThisName = "";
    Object StatusReturn = new Object();

    StatusReturn = service.UpdateGrantBillStatus(fundBox.Text, toBox.Text, fromBox.Text);
    var type = StatusReturn.GetType();
    var propertyName = type.Name;
    //var propertyValue = propertyName.GetValue(myObject, null);error here 
}
```

Comment: `Object StatusReturn = new Object();` should be the return type of the service, not `object` !

Comment: it is already is it not? StatusReturn = service.UpdateGrantBillStatus(fundBox.Text, toBox.Text, fromBox.Text);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dynamic d = service.UpdateGrantBillStatus(fundBox.Text, toBox.Text, fromBox.Text);
string result = (string)d[0].sentBatchTotal;
```

Comment: this worked with one minor edit "(string)d[0].sentBatchTotal;" Thanks a Million I have been struggling for hours here.

Comment: Also, you may want to add a try / catch just in case that property does not exist. Have fun!

Answer (score 3):

The following code uses reflection.

```
StatusReturn = service.UpdateGrantBillStatus(fundBox.Text, toBox.Text, fromBox.Text);
var type = StatusReturn.GetType();
var pi = type.GetProperty("sentBatchTotal");
if (pi != null) {
    var propertyValue = pi.GetValue(StatusReturn, null);
}
```

But can't you just the webservice-method return-type instead of object? Than you can just read the property directly.

Something like:

```
WhatEverTypeYourServiceReturns StatusReturn = service.UpdateGrantBillStatus(fundBox.Text, toBox.Text, fromBox.Text);
string sentBatchTotal = StatusReturn.sentBatchTotal;
```

Comment: this does not work it always returns null i suspect because the service return its an index property.

Comment: i dont control webservice... however i would have loved to figuere out how to do this with object reflection i dont understand how you would use object reflection with an indexed object.

Answer (score 3):

Don't declare your StatusReturn variable as an object type first.

```
//Object StatusReturn = new Object();

var StatusReturn = service.UpdateGrantBillStatus(fundBox.Text, toBox.Text, fromBox.Text);
if (StatusReturn.Count() > 0)
{
    var fixedAsset = StatusReturn[0];
}
```

Comment: Genius thank you i cant believe i have been struggling for hours.